# Suppressing right-click context menu on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, contextmenu, right-click

I have a canvas and when a user right clicks on it, a context menu appears. I also have a checkbox, and when that box is checked, I DON'T want the context menu to appear. The reason for this is that, when the checkbox is checked, the first two right clicks from the user will drop ellipses at the two points of the right clicks. Right now though, the context menu will popup on those two right clicks. Here's the relative code:

```
<Window x:Class="Testproj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testproj"
    xmlns:localConverters="clr-namespace:Testproj"
    x:Name="this"
    Height="650" Width="1091"
    Loaded="this_Loaded"
    Closing="this_Closing">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

<Grid Height="Auto">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="nullToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DockPanel>
                <CheckBox x:Name="scaleBox" Content="Scale" IsChecked="False" Checked="scaleischecked"/>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Viewbox Margin="0,23,0,157" x:Name="viewbox1" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas Margin="0,21,0,12" x:Name="canvas1" ClipToBounds="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" MouseWheel="Canvas_Zoom" MouseRightButtonDown="get_MousePosition"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="3138" Height="1260">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform x:Name="mt"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="nodeContextMenu" Visibility="{StaticResource converter}" >
                    <MenuItem x:Name="test1"  IsCheckable="False" Header="test1" Click="WaypointMenuItem_Click" >
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="test2" IsCheckable="False" Header="test2" Click="KnownObjectMenuItem_Click" >
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Canvas.ContextMenu>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind for the right-click on canvas:

```
    private void get_MousePosition(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (scaleBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            get_points(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

I've tried messing around with the isOpen property of the context-menu, but it always open on right click regardless if it's set to true or false.

Attempt at converter below. If this is correct, what is the proper way to bind the checkbox and contextmenu using this?

```
namespace Testproj
{
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (value != null)
        {
            visibility = (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return visibility;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a [ValueConverter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) or [MultiValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and then bind to the checkbox using the converter to dictate the state (i.e. enabled/disabled) of the contextmenu.

```
        <Canvas.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="contextmenu1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=scaleBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                <MenuItem x:Name="item1"  IsCheckable="False" Header="item2" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="item2" IsCheckable="False" Header="item1" />
            </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Not really sure how the converters work, but I understand what you mean. Is there another way to bind the checkbox to the contextmenu? I've never used converters before.

Comment: You need to learn. Else you're going to struggle as a XAML developer if you don't leverage XAML patterns.

Comment: Going to edit my answer with a converter attempt. Could you let me know if it's the right way to go about it?

Comment: You need to declare the valueconverter as a resource in your resources section of your XAML. Next you follow the snippet of XAML I provided in my answer. Place a break point on your ValueConverter implementation and step through the code to understand your logic when loading the app.

Comment: <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

Is that the correct way to declare it as a resource? Because when stepping though with the debugger, I get an error saying the resource couldn't be resolved.

Comment: You need to declare the namespace that conatins your class (i.e. valueconverter) first. Example: xmlns:localConverters="clr-namespace:Bizmonger.UILogic.Converters"

Comment: Ah forgot about that, thank you. Fixed that. Now it says "the resource "BooltoVisibilityConverter" could not be resolved. Upon going through the debugger "XamlParseException occured."

Comment: There's an inner exception in that which says "Cannot find resource named 'BoolToVisibilityConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive."

Comment: What's the name of your converter class? Update the name to the name your using.

Comment: The name is BoolToVisibilityConverter.cs

Comment: Make sure that the x:key is the name used everywhere within your xaml references

Comment: Says "An object of the type Testproj.BoolToVisibilityConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Visibility".

I have 'xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testproj"
        xmlns:localConverters="clr-namespace:Testproj"'
located at the top. Then the converter in Window.Resources.

Comment: My bad. I gave you misleading syntax for binding the visibility. Please reference my update and make the ElementName equal to the name of your checkbox.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. One more error I'm getting though. "The property 'Converter' was not found in type 'ContextMenu'.
Edit: Fixed, just a small syntax error.

Comment: Let me know if your valueconverter now executes.

Comment: I get a "BoolToVisibilityConverter" could not be resolved error. It points to the Converter={StaticResource } section. Going deeper in the exception, it says "provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension"

Comment: I gave you the wrong syntax. The converter should be contained inside the binding. View a code snippet example of wiring a valueconverter to a data binding within XAML. I'm typing this on my cell phone so I apologize for the syntax issues

Comment: Update: Doesn't seem to be working. Context menu still shows on right click w/ and w/o checkbox selected.

Comment: Yes. "The resource "BoolToVisibilityConverter" could not be resolved." It's pointing to inside the Converter=StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter. Now, when I change that to "converter" which is the x:key property of the resource, the error goes away, but doesn't affect the visibility of the contextmenu in any way.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the IsChecked value? Since I want the context menu to show only when scalebox.IsChecked = false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I figured out how to do it since I couldn't get the converter to work properly:

Set the ContextMenuService.IsEnabled property to false in the canvas. Then, in the code behind, set nodeContextMenu.IsOpen = true when the scalebox is not checked. This seems to do the trick.

```
<Canvas Margin="0,21,0,12" x:Name="canvas1" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False" />

if (scaleBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    get_Scaling(sender, e);
}
else
{
    nodeContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```